# The Stored Proc I have is running very slow / never finishes. Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So what I am essentially trying to do is grab data that is flagged in value_flag (which will involve joining numerous tables) and then manipulating / updating those entries in those tables (mostly the 'VALUE' table) based off some business rules / logic that I have. I have come up with some code (that should work) that is shown below but it takes many hours to run. Is there a more efficient way to do this?  My code is as follows:

```
create or replace procedure IMP_JOB IS
CURSOR c1 is
select v.value_id
     , vf.VALUE_FLAG_ID
     , sv.sub_value_id    
     , ff.form_Field_tx
     , v.hr_num
     , v.data_date
     , v.code
from sub s
join sub_value sv on s.sub_id = sv.sub_id
join value v on sv.value_id = v.value_id
join field f on sv.Field_id = ff.form_Field_id
join line l on ff.line_id = fl.form_line_id
join section s on fl.section_id = fs.form_section_id
join flagrel vf on sv.sub_value_id = vf.sub_value_id
join flag f on vf.value_flag_type_id = f.flag_id
where
(
((to_date(LPAD(V.DATA_DATE, 7, 0), 'DDDYYYY') = trunc(sysdate)) AND     fl.form_line_label_tx in ('Same Day', 'Same-Day'))
OR
(l.line_label_tx in ('V2', 'Daily'))
)
AND 
(
(flag_tx IN ('??', 'N'))
OR
v.value_nb is null
);
l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
v_value_id value.value_id%type;
v_calc_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
v_forecast_hr value.value_nb%type;
v_prior_hour_value value.value_nb%type;
v_prior_day_value value.value_nb%type;
--
BEGIN
--
OPEN c1;
LOOP 
--
        FETCH c1 into l_var;
          --
          SELECT GET_DA_VALUE(l_var.hr_num, l_var.Data_date, l_var.code)
          INTO v_forecast_hr
          FROM DUAL;
          --
      SELECT GET_PRIOR_HOUR_VALUE(l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_Date, l_var.code, l_var.form_Field_tx)
      INTO v_prior_hour_value
      FROM DUAL;
      --
      SELECT GET_PRIOR_DAY_VALUE(l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_Date, l_Var.code, l_var.form_field_Tx)
      INTO v_prior_day_value
      FROM DUAL;
      --
      --IF1
      IF l_var.form_field_tx = 'X'
      THEN
          --IF1A
          IF v_forecast_hr IS NOT NULL
          THEN
              Update Value
              SET Value_tx = v_forecast_hr 
              WHERE value_id = l_var.value_id;
              COMMIT;
              --
              Update Value_flag
              SET Value_Flag_Type_Id = 2
              WHERE sub_value_id = l_var.sub_value_id;                  
              COMMIT;
          --IF1A Continued
          ELSE
              --IF1A1
              IF v_prior_hour_value IS NULL
              THEN
                   --IF1A2
                  IF v_prior_day_value IS NULL
                  THEN
                      Update Value
                         SET Value_Tx = null
                        WHERE value_id = l_var.value_id;
                       COMMIT;
                 --
                    Update Value_flag
                       SET Value_Flag_Type_Id = 5
                     WHERE submission_value_id = l_var.sub_value_id;                  
                    COMMIT;
                  --IF1A2 Continued
                  ELSE
                    Update Value
                       SET Value_Tx = v_prior_day_value
                     WHERE value_id = l_var.value_id;
                    COMMIT;
                  --
                    Update Value_flag
                       SET Value_Flag_Type_Id = 7
                     WHERE subm_value_id = l_var.sub_value_id;                  
                    COMMIT;
                  --IF1A2 End
                  END IF;
              --IF1A1 Continued  
              ELSE
              Update Value
                 SET Value_Tx = v_prior_hour_value
               WHERE value_id = l_var.value_id;
               COMMIT;
              --
              Update Value_flag
                 SET Value_Flag_Type_Id = 9
               WHERE sub_value_id = l_var.sub_value_id;                  
              COMMIT;
              --IF1A1 End
              END IF;
          --IF1A End
          END IF;
      --IF1 Continued
      ELSIF l_var.form_field_tx = 'TX'
      THEN
          --IF1B
          IF v_prior_hour_value IS NULL
          THEN
              --IF1B1
                  IF v_prior_day_value IS NULL
                  THEN
                      Update Value
                         SET Value_Tx = null
                       WHERE value_id = l_var.value_id;
                      COMMIT;
                 --
                    Update Value_flag
                       SET Value_Flag_Type_Id = 02
                     WHERE sub_value_id = l_var.sub_value_id;                  
                    COMMIT;
              --IF1B1 Continued    
                  ELSE
                    Update Value
                       SET Value_Tx = v_prior_day_value
                     WHERE value_id = l_var.value_id;
                    COMMIT;
                  --
                    Update Value_flag
                       SET Value_Flag_Type_Id = 9
                     WHERE sub_value_id = l_var.sub_value_id;                  
                    COMMIT;
              --IF1B1 End
                  END IF;
          --IF1B Continued
          ELSE
              Update Value
                 SET Value_Tx = v_prior_hour_value
               WHERE value_id = l_var.value_id;
               COMMIT;
              --
              Update Value_flag
                 SET Value_Flag_Type_Id = 890
               WHERE sub_value_id = l_var.sub_value_id;                  
              COMMIT;          
          --IF1B End
          END IF;                
      --IF1 Continued
      ELSE
      null;
      --IF1 End
      END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
END IMP_JOB;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing here is looping over a result set and processing it row-by-row. That's not called "slow-by-slow" for nothing. SQL is a set oriented language and is most efficient when operating on sets.

1. Your procedure just updates `value` and `value_flag`, so the best thing to do is to rewrite this to turn it into two update statements. **This is the best thing you can do to improve performance.**
2. Your loop has cases for when `form_field_tx` is X or TX and hits an `ELSE NULL` in all other cases. Since you don't care about rows that are not X or TX, put that in your query's `WHERE` clause so you don't have to process those rows in the first place.
3. For your V.DATA_DATE clause, please please please tell me you are not storing dates as `VARCHAR2s`, because that's just bad. If so, you can rewrite this line as `v.data_date = TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DDDYYYY' )` so the TO_DATE doesn't have to be run for every row in your result set.
4. You *might* be able to get *some* performance improvement if you declared an array of your `l_var` and used `BULK COLLECT` to process this result set in chunks. See [this](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CGWLETXYUGGLX6Q516K3UWTIT.html) for an example of what I mean. **But** you will probably not get much performance improvement, since PL/SQL does this automatically behind the scenes now. I think the fetch size is 100 rows, but I'm not sure.

**Edit:**
So to convert this to a set of two update queries, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE value v
   SET value_tx = ( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... = v.value_id )
 WHERE v.value_id IN ( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... )
```

I'll be honest, you have like 10 different cases in three nested IF statements and I didn't try to follow it all. You want to break up your c1 cursor into two parts and use them in the `SELECTs` above.

The first subquery should return the new `value_tx` value for a given `v.value_id`. That subquery must return a *single* row for a given value_id. It will probably have a fairly complicated CASE statement, since you have so many different possibilites. Like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( form_field_tx = 'X' ) THEN
           COALESCE( GET_DA_VALUE(hr_num, Data_date, code),
           ... END
```

The second subquery should return just the `value_ids` of the rows in `value` you want to update. That one should be a lot simpler and would probably look pretty similar to the c1 query you have now, with a shorter list of columns.

Comment: Good list of advice, especially about importance of sets in SQL. I would add, *5. Don't commit after every statement*, which is bad for recoverability as well as performance.

Comment: Thanks for the sage advice. unfortunately the database that I am working with has dddyyyy as the date so I need to convert it :(

Comment: How would I make that into an update though (btw)? ive tried thinking it through but couldn't figure out the process flow to get this done. haha

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how we can help with performance issues without having the data. I do see a couple of small things in your code that might be improved.

Probably doesn't impact performance because Oracle handles DUAL very efficiently, but assign the value rather than using select into. This will help with readability:

```
        v_forecast_hr   := get_da_value( l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_date, l_var.code );

    v_prior_hour_value   :=
        get_prior_hour_value( l_var.hr_num
                            , l_var.data_date
                            , l_var.code
                            , l_var.form_field_tx );

    v_prior_day_value   :=
        get_prior_day_value( l_var.hr_num
                           , l_var.data_date
                           , l_var.code
                           , l_var.form_field_tx );
```

Readability is very important for trouble shooting. Your cursor **where** clause is a mess. I am wondering if you are processing more records than you expected. You can improve readability somewhat by getting rid of the excess parenthesis, such as around your 'IN' subsets:

```
(flag_tx IN ('??', 'N'))
```

becomes

```
flag_tx IN ('??', 'N')
```

You might also want to format your code. The first thing I did was throw it into TOAD and  run the PL/SQL formatter. I immediately discovered you are missing a semicolon after your cursor, which tells me that the code you pasted here is not the actual code with which you are working. As presented here, this will not compile.

Is there some reason you are committing after every update statement? This isn't SQL Server where blocking is an issue. A single commit just before

> end loop;

is all that is needed. If it weren't for the fact that this is taking hours, I would put a single commit outside of the loop.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. the reason I have the parentheses is because this is one (1) where clause: ((to_date(LPAD(V.DATA_DATE, 7, 0), 'DDDYYYY') = trunc(sysdate)) AND fl.form_line_label_tx in ('Same Day', 'Same-Day')) OR (l.line_label_tx in ('V2', 'Daily')))

Comment: so essentially wat this is saying is one/either of these scenarios must happen: the data_date must be from today and label_tx = 'Same Day' OR it must be V2, Daily.  Thanks for catching that by the way, I added the semi-colon back. I must've accidentally deleted it.

Comment: Right now I have only a couple thousand rows of data. (if that helps). This means that I am doing something inefficiently. haha.

Comment: @JohnWick Take your cursor select and surround it with **select count(*) c from (cursor select Here). This will give you a precise record count so that you know you are indeed working on the proper number of records.

Comment: @JohnWick I also know that Oracle does some buffering (50 records comes to mind, but don't take that to the bank) when you use a for statement for your loop rather than a cursor. ex:. `for c1 in (cursor select goes here) loop ...  end loop;`